# React 16.2.0 shows error "Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I was using react@15.6.2 but was trying to update to 16.2.0

I've deleted the node_modules folder, then execute `npm cache clean` and `npm install`

However, the console keeps showing this message

`UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.6.2 invalid`

And after I run my webpack server, the browser just throws an error message:

`Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined`

Why is the happening?

Here is what my package.json looks like:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "firebase": "^4.13.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
    "install": "^0.11.0",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "open-browser-webpack-plugin": "0.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.7",
    "react-route": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
```

Comment: find out what is depending on v15 `npm ls react`

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem.

What bothers me is that even if you delete the node_modules folder, the package version just stays the same(the old one). And I still don't know why

So I uninstall both `react` and `react-dom` due to the error message of `npm ls react` indicates that :
`npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^16.0.0, required by react-dom@16.2.0`

After re-installing them by executing `npm install react@16.2.0` and `npm install react-dom@16.2.0`, the error message of browser disappear ! :)